# php need assistance with regular expression

Tags: php, regex

I want to parse and expand the given strings in PHP.

From

```
0605052&&-5&-7&-8
0605052&&-4&-7
0605050&&-2&-4&-6&-8
```

To

```
0605052, 0605053 ,0605054 ,0605055, 0605057, 0605058
0605052,0605053,0605054,0605057
0605050,0605051,0605052,0605054,0605056,0605058
```

can someone help me with that? thanks in advance!

Comment: Try to put a bit more effort in writing your question. Be clearer about what you need, how are you trying to accomplish it, give examples of your expected output and your actual output. And do try to have this working on your own and come with something more specific. SO is not a code writing service. :)

Comment: you want to get 0605052 out of 0605052&&-5&-7&-8 ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is not very clear, but I think you mean a solution like this:

**Edited:** Now the hole ranges were shown and not only the specified numbers.

```
<?php
    $string = "0605052&&-5&-7&-8";
    $test = '/^([0-9]+)\&+/';
    preg_match($test, $string, $res);

    if (isset($res[1]))
    {
        $nr = $res[1];

        $test = '/\&\-([0-9])/';
        preg_match_all($test, $string, $res);

        $result[] = $nr;
        $nrPart = substr($nr, 0, -1);
        $firstPart = substr($nr, -1);

        if (isset($res[1]))
        {
            foreach ($res[1] as &$value)
            {
                if ($firstPart !== false)
                {
                    for ($i=$firstPart+1; $i<=$value; $i++)
                    {
                        $nr = $nrPart . $i;
                        $result[] = $nr;
                    }
                    $firstPart = false;
                }
                else
                {
                    $nr = $nrPart . $value;
                    $result[] = $nr;
                    $firstPart = $value;
                }
            }
        }
        var_dump($result);
    }
?>
```

This delivers:
result[0] = "0605052" 
result[1] = "0605053" 
result[2] = "0605054" 
result[3] = "0605055" 
result[4] = "0605057" 
result[5] = "0605058"

Comment: You are missing 0605053, 0605054 which are generated from the difference between the last number of the base and the first single number.

Comment: The question was not clearly before editing by @MYGz, so I thought that for every &-x there was wished only one result and not for every two $-x a range of results.

Answer (score 0):

I think a multi step approach is the best thing to do here.

E.g. take this as an example `0605052&&-5&-7&-8`:

1. Split at `-`. The result will be `0605052&&`, `5&`, `7&`, `8`
2. The first result `0605052&&` will help you create your base. Simply substring the numbers by finding first occurence of `&` and substring to the next to last number. Result will be `060505`. You will also need the last number, so get it as well (which is `2` in this case).
3. Get the remaining ends now, all `\d&` are simple to get, simply take the first character of the string (or if those can be more than one number, use substring with first occurence of `&` approach again).
4. The last number is simple: it is `8`.

Now you got all important values. You can generate your result:

The last number from 2., all numbers from 3. and the number from 4. together with your base are the first part. In addition, you need to generate all numbers from the last number of 2. and  the first result of 3. in a loop by a step of 1 and append it to your base.

Example Code:

```php
<?php
$str = '0605052&&-5&-7&-8';
$split = explode('-', $str);

$firstAmpBase = strpos($split[0], '&');
$base = substr($split[0], 0, $firstAmpBase - 1);
$firstEnd = substr($split[0], $firstAmpBase - 1, 1);
$ends = [];

$firstSingleNumber = substr($split[1], 0, strpos($split[1], '&'));
for ($i = $firstEnd; $i < $firstSingleNumber; $i++) {
    array_push($ends, $i);
}
array_push($ends, $firstSingleNumber);

for ($i = 2; $i < count($split) - 1; $i++) {
    array_push($ends, substr($split[$i], 0, strpos($split[$i], '&')));
}
array_push($ends, $split[count($split) - 1]);

foreach ($ends as $end) {
    echo $base . $end . '<br>';
}
?>
```

Output:

```
0605052
0605053
0605054
0605055
0605057
0605058
```